# Which is the most efficient way of taking input in Java?

Tags: java, optimization, io, user-input, inputstream

I am solving this [question](http://www.codechef.com/problems/INTEST/).

This is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int k = sc.nextInt();
        int[] t = new int[n];
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            t[i] = sc.nextInt();
            if (t[i] % k == 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);

    }
}
```

But when I submit it, it get's timed out. Please help me optimize this to as much as is possible.

Example

Input:

```
7 3
1
51
966369
7
9
999996
11
```

Output:

```
4
```

They say :

> You are expected to be able to process
>   at least 2.5MB of input data per
>   second at runtime.

Modified CODE

Thank you all...I modified my code and it worked...here it is....

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String[] input = br.readLine().split(" ");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(input[0]);
        int k = Integer.parseInt(input[1]);
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()) % k == 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
```

regards

shahensha

Comment: Why use `int[] t` if you are not using this array for any useful thing here? You could have use `int t` instead.

Comment: This looks like input code for an ACM-ICPC problem, is this the entire "program"? From where is it timing out? an online judge? Can you give us some sample input?

Comment: yes that's the entire program...and they run the code on their servers....they have given us 8 seconds for this particular program....they say " You are expected to be able to process at least 2.5MB of input data per second at runtime."

Comment: is the input formatted like that? or do you have an unknown amount of whitespace between each int? or is each number o a different line?

Comment: There is a space between n and k in the first line...and thereafter, each number is on a new line....

Comment: @Argote - I've formatted the Input and Output sections to make them clearer.

Comment: In this case you can use `BufferedReader` as I mentioned in the answer, get the first line, use `String.split` on the String and parse each element, then read each line and put it into an `Integer.parseInt` and use that in the modulo operation.

Comment: most efficient way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be slightly faster, based on limc's solution, `BufferedReader` should be faster still though.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int k = sc.nextInt();
        int count = 0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                if (sc.nextInt() % k == 0) {
                    count++;
                }
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = sc.nextInt();
int k = sc.nextInt();
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (sc.nextInt() % k == 0) {
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: does this really change input speed?

Comment: The advantage to this (speed-wise) is that it doesn't instantiate the array (plus it uses less memory), the input speed should be the same.

Comment: It depends on his `n`. If the value for `n` is huge, then you are creating a huge `int` array in the memory for nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider reading big chunks of input and then get the numbers from there.

Other change is, you may use `Integer.parseInt()` instead of `Scanner.nextInt()` although I don't know the details of each one, somethings tells me Scanner version performs a bit more computation to know if the input is correct. Another alternative is to convert the number yourself ( although Integer.parseInt should be fast enough )

Create a sample input, and measure your code, change a bit here and there and see what the difference is.

Measure, measure!

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedReader` is supposed to be faster than `Scanner`. You will need to parse everything yourself though and depending on your implementation it could be worse.

Comment: Thanks a lot Argote! I implemented it with BufferedReader and without the array and it worked....Should I post the corrected code for others....???